# Shopify mini cart show number of products not total amount

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am using Shopify and want the minicart to show the number of products/items, not the total of the cart.  For example if I sell 3 metres of one fabric and then 4 metres of another fabric then it says 2 not 7.

I have managed to amend the header coding with cart.items.size (instead of cart.item_count) and this works fine when a page first loads.  However if I am on a product page and add products, the mini cart updates but it counts the total again, not the number of fabrics.  If I refresh the page then it is fine again.

I have tried editing the javascript to read cart.items.size instead of cart.item_count, but it just comes up with 'undefined' when the items are added to the cart.

I have no experience of editing javascript so can someone point me in the right direction please.  If you need any extra code or information please do say, apologies if I miss anything.

Here is the header code that is working:

```
<div class="mini-cart-wrap" href="#">
  {% if settings.cart-icon == "cart" %}
    {% include 'icon' with 'cart' %}
  {% else %}
    {% include 'icon' with 'bag' %}
  {% endif %}
  <label><span class="item-count">{{ cart.items.size }}</span> {{ 'layout.header.item_count' | t: count: cart.items.size }}</label>
  <div class="mini-cart {% if shop.customer_accounts_enabled %}account-enabled{% endif %} {% if cart.items.size == 0 %}empty-cart{% endif %}">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="mini-cart-items-wrap">

        <p class="no-items">{{ 'layout.header.no_items' | t }}</p>

        {% for item in cart.items %}
        <div id="item-{{ item.id }}" class="item clearfix">
          <div class="image-wrap">
            <img alt="{{ item.product.title }}" src="{{ item | img_url: 'small' }}">
            <a class="{% if settings.product-image-borders %}overlay{% endif %}" href="{{ item.url }}"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="details">
            {% if settings.show-brand-names %}
              <p class="brand">{{ item.vendor | link_to_vendor }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            <p class="title"><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.product.title }}</a><span class="quantity">× <span class="count">{{ item.quantity }}</span></span></p>
            <p class="price"><span class="money">{{ item.line_price | money }}</span></p>
            {% unless item.variant.title == 'Default Title' %}<p class="variant">{{ item.variant.title }}</p>{% endunless %}
            {% if item.properties %}
              {% for property in item.properties %}
                {% unless property.last == blank %}
                  <p class="property">
                    <span class="property-label">{{ property.first }}:</span>
                    {% if property.last contains '/uploads/' %}
                      <a class="property-image" href="{{ property.last }}">{{ property.last | split: '/' | last }}</a>
                    {% else %}
                      <span class="property-value">{{ property.last }}</span>
                    {% endif %}
                  </p>
                {% endunless %}
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="options clearfix">
      <a class="action-button view-cart desaturated" href="/cart">{{ 'layout.header.view_cart' | t }}</a>
      <a class="action-button checkout" href="/checkout">{{ 'layout.header.checkout' | t }}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the current javascript (unedited)

```
ProductView.prototype.updateMiniCart = function(cart) {
  var i, item, itemProperties, itemText, j, len, miniCartItemsWrap, productPrice, propertiesArray, propertyKeysArray, ref, variant;
  miniCartItemsWrap = $(".mini-cart-items-wrap");
  miniCartItemsWrap.empty();
  if (cart.item_count !== 1) {
    itemText = Theme.cartItemsOther;
  } else {
    itemText = Theme.cartItemsOne;
    $(".mini-cart .options").show();
    miniCartItemsWrap.find(".no-items").hide();
  }
  $(".mini-cart-wrap label").html("<span class='item-count'>" + cart.item_count + "</span> " + itemText);
  ref = cart.items;
  for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
    item = ref[j];
    productPrice = Shopify.formatMoney(item.line_price, Theme.moneyFormat);
    variant = item.variant_title ? "<p class='variant'>" + item.variant_title + "</p>" : "";
    itemProperties = "";
    if (item.properties) {
      propertyKeysArray = Object.keys(item.properties);
      propertiesArray = _.values(item.properties);
      i = 0;
      while (i < propertyKeysArray.length) {
        if (propertiesArray[i].length) {
          itemProperties = itemProperties + ("<p class=\"property\">\n    <span class=\"property-label\">" + propertyKeysArray[i] + ":</span>\n    <span class=\"property-value\">" + propertiesArray[i] + "</span>\n</p>");
        }
        i++;
      }
    }
    miniCartItemsWrap.append("<div id=\"item-" + item.variant_id + "\" class=\"item clearfix\">\n    <div class=\"image-wrap\">\n        <img alt=\"" + item.title + "\" src=\"" + item.image + "\">\n        <a class=\"overlay\" href=\"" + item.url + "\"></a>\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"details\">\n        <p class=\"brand\">" + item.vendor + "</p>\n        <p class=\"title\"><a href=\"" + item.url + "\">" + item.product_title + "</a><span class=\"quantity\">× <span class=\"count\">" + item.quantity + "</span></span></p>\n        <p class=\"price\"><span class=\"money\">" + productPrice + "</span></p>\n        " + variant + "\n        " + itemProperties + "\n    </div>\n</div>");
  }
  if (Theme.currencySwitcher) {
    return $(document.body).trigger("switch-currency");
  }
};
```

and also here (for the quick view)

```
ProductView.prototype.updateMiniCart = function(cart) {
  var i, item, itemProperties, itemText, j, len, miniCartItemsWrap, productPrice, propertiesArray, propertyKeysArray, ref, variant;
  miniCartItemsWrap = $(".mini-cart-items-wrap");
  miniCartItemsWrap.empty();
  if (cart.item_count !== 1) {
    itemText = Theme.cartItemsOther;
  } else {
    itemText = Theme.cartItemsOne;
    $(".mini-cart .options").show();
    miniCartItemsWrap.find(".no-items").hide();
  }
  $(".mini-cart-wrap label").html("<span class='item-count'>" + cart.item_count + "</span> " + itemText);
  ref = cart.items;
  for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
    item = ref[j];
    productPrice = Shopify.formatMoney(item.line_price, Theme.moneyFormat);
    variant = item.variant_title ? "<p class='variant'>" + item.variant_title + "</p>" : "";
    itemProperties = "";
    if (item.properties) {
      propertyKeysArray = Object.keys(item.properties);
      propertiesArray = _.values(item.properties);
      i = 0;
      while (i < propertyKeysArray.length) {
        if (propertiesArray[i].length) {
          itemProperties = itemProperties + ("<p class=\"property\">\n    <span class=\"property-label\">" + propertyKeysArray[i] + ":</span>\n    <span class=\"property-value\">" + propertiesArray[i] + "</span>\n</p>");
        }
        i++;
      }
    }
    miniCartItemsWrap.append("<div id=\"item-" + item.variant_id + "\" class=\"item clearfix\">\n    <div class=\"image-wrap\">\n        <img alt=\"" + item.title + "\" src=\"" + item.image + "\">\n        <a class=\"overlay\" href=\"" + item.url + "\"></a>\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"details\">\n        <p class=\"brand\">" + item.vendor + "</p>\n        <p class=\"title\"><a href=\"" + item.url + "\">" + item.product_title + "</a><span class=\"quantity\">× <span class=\"count\">" + item.quantity + "</span></span></p>\n        <p class=\"price\"><span class=\"money\">" + productPrice + "</span></p>\n        " + variant + "\n        " + itemProperties + "\n    </div>\n</div>");
  }
  if (Theme.currencySwitcher) {
    return $(document.body).trigger("switch-currency");
  }
};
```

Comment: Ideally, your code should work. Can I see an example to figure the bug?

Comment: Joseph's answer was the key - I needed cart.items.length instead of cart.items.size in the javascript.  Thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquid uses `array.size` to determine the size of an array. That's why your header is working from your Liquid template.

JavaScript, on the other hand, uses `array.length` to determine the size of the array. Try replacing `cart.items.size` in your JavaScript with `cart.items.length`

Comment: I'm not sure how that'd work. As I see the javascript already uses `.length` instead of `.size`. And the `cart` in JS should be coming from `/cart.js` in which cart.items is a javascript array. Am I seeing something wrong?

Comment: @HymnZ Notice that in the liquid header code, the 7th line contains `<span class="item-count">{{ cart.items.size }}</span>`. This is an example of `.size` being used. However, in the first chunk of JavaScript, on the 12th line `$(".mini-cart-wrap label").html("<span class='item-count'>" + cart.item_count + "</span> " + itemText);` the user was trying to replace `cart.item_count` with `cart.items.size`. They should have instead replaced that with `cart.items.length`